# ¿Cómo le doy el formato Date a un string con varias fechas?

Tags: javascript, date

Necesito darle formato Date (2019-09-10) a este string:

```
 var fechas = '20190910,20190910,20190910,20190910,20190910#';
```

Comment: Te sugiero que primero hagas un `split` por comas, luego a cada `String` que cuente 4 y ponga un guion, luego que cuente 2 y ponga otro guion. Quedando la cosa asi por pasos : 1.  De esto `'20190910,20190910,20190910,20190910,20190910#'` pasa a un array de esto `20190910` luego **cuentas 4 y separas y luego dos y separas , ambos por guiones o barras** quedando asi `2019-09-10`. Ya simplemente le tienes que hacer un `Date.parse(String)` y lo tendras

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos te dejo la siguiente solución:

```js
//mis fechas
data = '20190910,20190910,20190910,20190910,20190910';
//separo mis fechas por las cosas y las coloca en un array(result)
result = data.split(',');
//determina la posicion donde se pondra el separador(-)
positionCuarta = 4;
//determina la posicion donde se pondra el separador(-)
positionSeptima = 7;
//mi separador
b = '-';

//recorro el resultado del split(las fechas)
for(i=0;i<result.length; i++){
  //obtengo la fecha en una variable temporal
  fechaTemporal = result[i];
  //obtengo el primer formato de fecha(2019-0910)
  var fechaUno = [fechaTemporal.slice(0, positionCuarta), b, fechaTemporal.slice(positionCuarta)].join('');
  //obtengo la fecha final(2019-09-10)
  var fechaFinal = [fechaUno.slice(0, positionSeptima), b, fechaUno.slice(positionSeptima)].join('');
  console.log(fechaFinal);
}
```

**Explicación:**

**data** sera donde contenga  mis fechas.

**split** Me permite separar una cadena de texto mediante algun criterio en este caso separo las fechas por la coma(,) y este me lo devuelve en un array(result).

**positionCuarta** y **positionSeptima** determinan la posicion donde colocare el separador de fechas en este caso el guion medio puede ser el que desees.

**b** mi separador puedes colocar el que desees.

Ahora bien a continuacion viene mi ciclo for que es donde recorro uno a uno el array que obtuve del split(result).

dentro de esto hay algo quiza confuso o no depende tu nivel pero te lo explicare, primero obtengo el valor en una variable temporal la cual la denomino **fechaTemporal** porque esta no es la fecha aun convertida(20190910).

seguido tengo lo siguiente:

```
 var fechaUno = [fechaTemporal.slice(0, positionCuarta), b, fechaTemporal.slice(positionCuarta)].join('');
```

inicio tomando la **fechaTemporal** la misma empieza a recorrer desde la posicion 0 hasta la posicion deseada en este caso **positionCuarta** en dicha posicion agrega o coloca **b** que en este caso es el separador deseado.

Lo mismo hace la siguiente linea solo que en distinta posicion para separar lo que seria mes y dia de la fecha y finalmente por consola(console.log) obtengo la resultante o **fechaFinal**

espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograr fácilmente tu cometido haciendo uso de un reemplazo de texto por medio de una expresión regular similar a la siguiente:

```
fechas.replace(new RegExp(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g), '$1-$2-$3')
```